# how can i add array of objects in schemaless mongoose?

Tags: angularjs, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

```
**model schema**
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;


var item = new Schema({
   name:{type: String, 
   required: true},
   price:{type: String}
 })


 var object=new Schema({
 name:{type: String, 
    required: true},
    items: [item]
});
```

> api.js, posting data to server

```
router.post('/objectss', function(req, res){ 

  var object= new Object(); **
```

> how can i save array of objects in array

**

```
    object.items.push({firstName: req.body.fname, lastName:      req.body.lname});
    object.name = req.body.name;
        object.save(function (err) {
        if(err) throw err;

        res.json({success: true, message:'allahuakbar'});

    });
```

// saved!

});

> angularjs controller

$scope.addProduct = function(){

```
  $scope.items.push({
     fname: $scope.item.fname,
     lname: $scope.item.lname

  });

  $scope.item = {};
```

}

```
$scope.submitx = function(inv, item){

        console.log(inv);

        var object = {
      name:inv.name,
      fname:items.fname,
     totalValue:       0
  }
            PostBlog.createInvoice(objects).then(function(data){
          console.log(data);
        });
            $scope.objects= {};
      }
```

please see this code and help me! struggling over weeks . there is array of object like a["name":carrot, "price":24, "":, etc]

Comment: Your question is not very succinct, so little tough to understand what you are trying to do here. If I have understood correctly, you want to store objects in `items`, but you don't know the exact fields of those items. In that case, define `items` as `items: []`, rather than defining like `items: [item]`. Now you can push any object inside `items`.

Answer (score 0):

those who get stuck refer to this instead of using method

```
 router.post('/invoices', function(req, res){ //by making route in from              


    var invoice = new Invoice();

       for (var i = 0; i < req.body.length; i++) {

 invoice.items.push({name:req.body.fname[i].fname});
  } 
   invoice.name = req.body.name;
    //invoice.items.insertMany(items, function(error, next) {
        invoice.save(function (err) {
        if(err) throw err;

        res.json({success: true, message:'allahuakbar'});

    });



  // saved!

 });
```